# SELECT in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I don't know how to do SELECT * FROM  in Hibernate without Query.    I.e. I can do smt like this:

```
Session session = ...;
JavaBean jb = ...;
...
session.save(jb); // I'm adding jb
session.update(jb); // I'm updating jb
session.delete(jb); // I'm deleting jb
```

But I don't know how to select from session. The only way that I know is

```
list = session.createQuery("from JavaBean").list();
```

Comment: So, what exactly do you want? The `.createQuery` way is the correct one.

Comment: That's the way to do. You define a POJO and select all columns which are defined there. Anyway, what do you want to do with columns which you didn't know at programming time?

Comment: Take a look at Hibernate Criteria API : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: I want to create method that will give me a list of every object in my table, i.e List getAll(Class clazz) {...}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all the instances of JavaBean, use Hibernate Criteria API :

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(JavaBean.class);
List javaBeans = criteria.list();
```

Comment: Is there any generic criteria that will return List<JavaBean>?

Answer (score 2):

```
Criteria crit=session.createCriteria(Class object of a pojo class)
EX:
Criteria crit=session.createCriteria(Employee.class)
List list=crit.list();
```

If the above criteria is executed then it loads all employees i.e all objects of Employee pojo class from the DataBase

Internally hibernate stores each row of Employee in an object Employee class and all Employee class objects are stored in a list and finally hibernate returns that list object to our java application

While iterating the collection(List) we need to typecast each object into pojo class type.

```
 Iterator it=list.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
 {
  Employee e=(Employee)it.next();
 ..............
 ..............

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question is:

```
List selectAll(Class clazz) {
    return session.createCriteria(clazz).list();
}
```

Look more at: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Thanks to overmeulen

Comment: Actually we wrote it at the same time ... I'm just slower than him at typing :)